# How to find out whether a window with the given name is open

Tags: javascript, window

I want to open the popup window on first visit. If the pop up is closed, I want to reopen the pop up on next refresh. I tried with cookies, but I could not figure out how to be notified of closing the window to delete the cookie.

Is it possible to learn if window is open by using `window.name`?

like

```
if (window.name==MsgWindow) 
{
    openWin();
}

function openWin()
{
    myWindow=window.open('','MsgWindow','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This window's name is: " + myWindow.name + "</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no direct method to check whether a window is still open if you only have the window's name.

However, for your case you could do the following:

```
// get reference to 'MsgWindow' (will open a new blank window if popup has been closed)
var popupWindow = window.open('', 'MsgWindow', 'width=200,height=100');

// keep popup window in background
window.focus();

// if popup window is blank (= has been closed before), load content
if (popupWindow.location.href == "about:blank") {
    popupWindow.location.href == /* your popup url here */;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, But no luck. Actually my pop up window has player to play the song.So when open the site the popup will start play the song. player should not intreputed in main window navigations.This is what i'm tring to do

Answer (score 0):

If you want an event that fires before the window closes, you can try `window.onbeforeunload`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below

```
var myWindow = "";

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  if(myWindow == "" || myWindow.closed){
            openWin();
  }
};

function openWin(){
    myWindow=window.open('','MsgWindow','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This window's name is: " + myWindow.name + "</p>");
}
```

Comment: pop window should not refreshed on every main window refresh.please read my comment on julian

Comment: ops my falt.. i have wrongly mentioned the conditions in if loop... have updated