# How to check whether a Browser Window is Opened or not in JSF or Primefaces?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am using `jsf` and `primefaces`.

I have a Form in which i have a `StudentId` input Text and a command Link to View `Student Details` in a new `Pop-Up` and a `Get` Command Button to display

[image]

I want to Achieve this When i Click on Get Button.

- if the pop-up window is not Opened before then dont open a Pop-Up.
- if the pop-up window is already opened, then refresh that window with new arguments.

Here is my Code :

**View page :**

```
...//js code is below ..

<h:outputText value="StudentId :" />
        <p:inputText value="#{myController.studentId}" >
            <pe:keyFilter mask="num"/>
        </p:inputText>
    <p:commandButton value="Get" actionListener="#{myController.getStudentMarksDetails(myController.studentId)}" >
     
<p:commandLink onclick="openWindow('http://www.google.com','pageName')" >
        <h:outputText value="Student Info "> 
</p:commandLink>

    ...//Displays Student Marks
```

**MyController**

```
public Student getStudentMarksDetails(Long studentId){
     //Some Code to Get the Student Marks
    
    // I want to Check whether a Pop-Up already exists or not, if pop-up is opened then refresh with this url
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("updatePopUpWindow('http://stackoverflow.com','pageName');");
    
}
```

**My JS**

```
  var myWindow;
    //Opens in the Same window 
    function openWindow(url, name){
          myWindow = window.open(url, name,'status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,resizable,width=1008,height=690,scrollbars,left=100,top=50,').focus();
    }
     
    // To check whether a Pop-Up window is opened or not 
    //if the pop-up window with pageName is not Opened before then dont open a Pop-Up.
    //if the pop-up window is already opened, then refresh that window with new arguments.
    
    function updatePopUpWindow(url, name){
        if(myWindow!=null){
            if(!myWindow.closed){
                 myWindow.close();
            }
        }
     //Check the condition Here
        myWindow = window.open(url, name,'status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,resizable,width=1008,height=690,scrollbars,left=100,top=50,').focus();
        
    }
```

**I tried Placing this Condition but no use:**

```
if(myWindow.name == name){
                myWindow = window.open(url, name,'status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no,resizable,width=1008,height=690,scrollbars,left=100,top=50,').focus();
            }
```

I referred many [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952385/how-to-find-out-whether-a-window-with-the-given-name-is-open), but unable to solve the way i need.

How to implement this issue in `JQuery` as `JS` properties are independent to Browsers

**Updated Comments:**
I cannot use a PF Dialog as i dont have any idea of how and What Type of Data  and View will come from that External Service Link. Think that i am not the author of the URL which i pass to get the Student Details.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use popups instead of a PF modal dialog?

Comment: @perissf I want to open a new Window, with url appended with studentId which get the student info. I want a new Browser window to be opened, not a Dialog!

Comment: @all In my case the Student Info details are provided by another External Project, so if i have to open a New Window and pass the URL with StudentId to call the External Service of another Project! it is not a case i can use a PF Dialog !

Comment: still don't understand why you can't use it the way I suggested...you have full control over dialog, you have full control over URL you pass - what else do you need?

Comment: @Dodek i want a Window to be opened because, we can view the student details info even if we perform any other action on the parent page leaving the StudentDetailsInfo window as it is.

Comment: @Dodek My context is not about using PF Dialog, it is all about why i am not able to find the window properties, is it because i am using Jsf and Js and Primefaces. i want to know this point from this question. Thank u :P

Answer (score 0):

I think that it **may**(and also may not) be the case you can use PF Dialog. Depends on the page you want to show in it. I used following example to show content of external page in a dialog:

Managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    private String myURL;

    public Bean() {
        myURL = "http://www.stuba.sk/english.html";
    }

    public void handleUpdateDialog(){
         myURL = "http://www.stuba.sk/english/news/news.html";
    }
    //getters and setters
    ...
}
```

xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Show Dialog" oncomplete="dlg.show();" update="dlgId"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Update Dialog" actionListener="#{bean.handleUpdateDialog}" oncomplete="dlg.show();" update="dlgId"/>

    <p:dialog id="dlgId" widgetVar="dlg">
        <iframe frameborder="0" align="left"
               src="#{bean.myURL}" id="someId" scrolling="auto"
               width="600" height="500">
        </iframe>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

As you can see, I used an iframe in PF Dialog, which I can update(also refresh). There are some pros and cons if you would like to use it like this. The good news for you is that you **can refresh** this dialog. **However, the main drawback** of this solution is that it **doesn't work for every external page** as there are many pages which can't be shown in frame due to 'X-Frame-Options' setting (such as google.com, facebook.com ...), which you can't affect unless you are the author of the page.

Comment: I dont want to have a PF Dialog.

Comment: Please see my Updated Comments